# How to perform CRUD operations on a Heroku DB from a Heroku Java Web app

Tags: java, postgresql, rest, heroku

I have a simple Java web app deployed in Heroku at [this link](https://wallpostapi.herokuapp.com/) and I've also attached a Heroku `hobby-dev` **POSTGRES** database to it.

I'm trying to implement RESTful web services in my web app and I want it to perform simple CRUD operations on the Heroku DB based on the type of request it receives. I found a tutorial on Heroku developer's site on how RESTful APIs could be built using MEAN stack and Node.js and how Heroku DB could be accessed, but nothing on how the same could be done in Java web app.

Can anyone please help me implement RESTful web services in my Heroku-Java Web app that would communicate with Heroku database?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Use JDBC to connect to the database and you can easily perform crud operations.

For ex:

private static Connection getConnection() throws URISyntaxException,SQLException{

```
URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));
String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + ':' + dbUri.getPort() + dbUri.getPath();

return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password);
```

}